# RegEx con misma vocal al inico y al final de string

Tags: javascript, regex

Consideremos un RegEx que debe identificar, cuando se tiene **la misma vocal, al inicio y al final de un String**.

Por ejemplo el String **"abcda"**.

Se intentó lo siguiente:

```
const regex = /([aeiou]).*\1/;
```

Aparentemente este RegEx funcionó muy bien, sin embargo, cuando se tiene la misma vocal, al inicio y en una posición antes del final del String, la expresión termina de evaluar y la da por valida.

Por ejemplo el string **"aewxyzae"**.
La regex termina de evaluar en **"aewxyza"**, descartando la última posición **"e"**.

Es decir el RegEx que se intentó, termina su ejecución en la posición **[n-1]** del String, en vez de evaluar cada posición hasta el final.

No entiendo porque el regEx no termina de evaluar hasta el final.
¿Cómo se puede implementar colegas?
Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes agregar el **delimitador** `^` (inicio de linea) y `$` (fin de linea) para delimitar la cadena completa

```
const regex = /^([aeiou]).*\1$/;
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#anchors

Comment: Funciona, además la guía de Microsoft es muy buena, Saludos.

Comment: Si es una buena guia rapida, acutalice el link a la version en español